# Update Framework from 3.1 to 5 for Azure Function will raise this error "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I built an Azure Function and the Target framework was 3.1, so i change it to 5, as follow:-

[image]

but after doing so, i start getting this error:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified
```

[image]

any advice how i can use .net 5 inside my azure function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by version compatibility. If the.NET version is upgraded from.NET 3.1 to.NET 5 or 6, this error will usually appear.

you need to change the Azure functions version to v4 and it fixes this error.

**Solution:**
Azure Functions project  **.csproj**  file:

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=azurecli) for more details.

**Another way installs latest version through npm package**

install the Azure Function Core Tools on the build agent using this npm command:

`npm install azure-functions-core-tools -g`

**NOTE:  this installs  `azure-functions-core-tools@3.0.3904`  (version 3.x - NOT the latest version 4.x).**

installed Azure Function Core Tools (v4), e.g. by installing with this npm command.

`npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true`